# apache/nifi docker: how to commit changes to new container

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I'm new to apache/nifi and run it with :

```
docker run --name nifi -p 8081:8080 -d apache/nifi:latest
```

and then dragged some processors. 
And then I tried to save them as new image using:

```
 docker commit [container ID] apache/nifi:latest
```

But it does not save the changes when I run the new committed image. 
Please advice me if any mistake. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
At first I launched nifi with:

```
docker run --name nifi -p 8081:8080 -d apache/nifi:latest
```

This is the group I added on the web UI: 
[image]

I want to save the container so I committed with following command:

```
docker commit 1e7 apache/nifi:latest2
```

we can see 2 nifi images here: 
[image]

Then I run:

```
docker run --name newnifi -p 8080:8080 -d apache/nifi:latest2
```

to chekc if the changes are saved in the new image. But the Web UI is empty and the group is not there. 
[image]

Comment: When you commit the image, try to use the image name for specific one not the similar to the original.

Comment: different tag makes sure that the name is different . I am using different name still facing same issue. @Lamanus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker commit` is for creating a new image from a container’s changes, meaning when you update or add new config or install new software, thus creating a new template images. Simply issue the `docker stop NAME_OF_CONTAINER` and when you would like to restart it `docker start NAME_OF_CONTAINER`

Comment: do you know how to save this container as image? I want to put it on docker hub to let other computer to use it. Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the question , why is it selected as approved answer. I am facing same issue, looking for solution

Answer (score 2):

This is coming from discussion on [official slack channel](https://apachenifi.slack.com/archives/C0L9VCD47/p1596653142278600) for Apache Nifi.

Looks like the flow definitions are stored in the `flow.xml.gz` in the `/conf` directory.
The [`apache/nifi` docker image](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile) defines this folder as volume.

Directories defined as volumes are not committed to images created from existing containers. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description.
That's why the processors and groups are not showing up in the new image.

These are the alternatives to consider:

1. Copying the `flow.xml.gz` file to your new container.
2. Exporting a template of your flow (this is deprecated but still usable).
3. Using `NiFi Registry` to store your flow definition, then import from there.